# Delete duplicate rows based on two values in sql

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm new to sql and I can't work out how to delete duplicate rows, I have a table like this called 'till_total':

| till_id | total |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 80 |
| 1 | 80 |
| 1 | 60 |
| 2 | 30 |
| 2 | 30 |
| 2 | 50 |

I want to only delete full duplicate rows so the table ends up like this

| till_id | total |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 80 |
| 1 | 60 |
| 2 | 30 |
| 2 | 50 |

I wrote this code to try and do it

```
SELECT till_id, total, COUNT(*) AS CNT
FROM till_total
GROUP BY till_id, total
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
ORDER BY till_id;
```

But that seems to delete all rows where the till_id is repeated. Could anyone help me with this?

Comment: Ironic that this is a duplicate question :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Good, old `ROWID` approach:

Before:

```
SQL> select * from till_total;

   TILL_ID      TOTAL
---------- ----------
         1         80
         1         80
         1         60
         2         30
         2         30
         2         50

6 rows selected.
```

Delete duplicates:

```
SQL> delete from till_total a
  2  where a.rowid > (select min(b.rowid)
  3                   from till_total b
  4                   where b.till_id = a.till_id
  5                     and b.total = a.total
  6                  );

2 rows deleted.
```

After:

```
SQL> select * from till_total;

   TILL_ID      TOTAL
---------- ----------
         1         80
         1         60
         2         30
         2         50

SQL>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
WITH till_total AS (
  SELECT till_id
     row_number() OVER(PARTITION BY till_id ORDER BY desc) AS row
  FROM TABLE
)
DELETE till_total WHERE row > 1
```

This might work for you, deleting rows that are more than 1 duplicate, not less than 1.

Comment: Nope, that won't work. Did you try it?